# Trying to get the Text inside a <ul> tag but its only returning the First item Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

this is the structure of the unodered list

[structure of the unodered list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JEhTM.jpg)

i want to get the value of "var" and "time" to two strings and save them in a ArrayList

```
List<String[]> finalResult = new ArrayList<>();
```

This is what i tried

```
 List<WebElement> typeElements =driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"container\"]/section[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/ul/li"));
        for(int i=0;i<typeElements.size();i++){
            WebElement typeSingle = typeElements.get(i);
            String stName = typeSingle.findElement(By.xpath("//div/a/var")).getText();
            String stTime = typeSingle.findElement(By.xpath("//div/a/time")).getText();
            String singleType[] =stName,stTime};
            finalResult.add(singleType);

        }
```

im getting total of 13 items in the

> finalResult

variable. but all the items are same

> {"title1","00:23"}
>
> {"title1","00:23"}
>
> {"title1","00:23"}....

i want them to be like this

> {"title1","00:23"}
>
> {"title2","00:31"}.....

what am i doing wrong?

***Edit*

On each itterations inside the for loop **typeSingle**
is refering to different id's,
but **stName** , **stTime** variables are same

Comment: Just put a debug point and make sure, you're getting a different `WebElement` for `typeSingle` everytime.

Comment: What happens if you use for `stName` this locator -`"/div/a/var"`? A child `div`, not just descendant.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Changing this

```
 String stName = typeSingle.findElement(By.xpath("//div/a/var")).getText();
 String stTime = typeSingle.findElement(By.xpath("//div/a/time")).getText();
```

to this solved the issue

```
String stName = typeSingle.findElement(By.xpath("div/a/var")).getText();
String stTime = typeSingle.findElement(By.xpath("div/a/time")).getText();
```

Answer (score 0):

To get child element with xpath you need to use `./`:

```
String stName = typeSingle.findElement(By.xpath("./div/a/var")).getText();
String stTime = typeSingle.findElement(By.xpath("./div/a/time")).getText();
```

Or use css selector:

```
String stName = typeSingle.findElement(By.cssSelector("var")).getText();
String stTime = typeSingle.findElement(By.cssSelector("time")).getText();
```